# Play 2.1.1 - template error while passing list of Map value from controller

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I would like to pass a list of map from controller to template. I am getting error while compiling template its saying "not found: value beerMap"  could someone please help me??

I tried this way..

ControllerClass:

```
public static Result index(){
Map<String, String> beerMap=null;
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> beerList =
new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
for(ViewRow row : result) {
      Map<String, String> parsedDoc = gson.fromJson(
      (String)row.getDocument(), HashMap.class);
      beerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
      beerMap.put("name", row.getName());
 }
beerList.add(beerMap);
return ok(index.render(beerList));
}
```

I tried to define templete like that

```
@(beerList: List[Map[String,String]])
@for(beerMap <- beerList){
          @beerMap.map { beer =>
               <tr>
                        <td><a href="/beers/show/@beer.name">@beer.name</a></td>
                    </tr>
                   }
                  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of struggling with Maps in the views, you'll probably do it faster with custom model, you don't need to annotate it with `@Entity` or extend with `Model` in such case Ebean will not try to generate a DB table for that,

Benefits: you can add some validation or pre-processing in the model's constructor especially when data incoming from json *may* contain some errors. Also you can add some methods that will give you some prepared values (ie. toString() ). As you can see working with it in the views is much more comfortable than with Maps, sample:

`models/Beer.java`

```
package models;

public class Beer {

    public String name;
    public String url;
    public String description;

    public Beer(String name, String url) {
        this.name = name;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

some controller...

```
public static Result index() {
    List<Beer> beers = new ArrayList<Beer>();

    // some dummy data
    beers.add(new Beer("Beer A", "beer_a"));
    beers.add(new Beer("Beer B", "beer_b"));

    Beer beerC =new Beer("Beer C", "beer_c");
    beerC.description= "Beer C has additional description";

    beers.add(beerC);

    return ok(index.render(beers));
}
```

`index view`

```
@(beers: List[Beer])

@main("List of beers") {

    @for(beer <- beers){
        <div>
            <h1>@beer</h1>
            <h2>@beer.description</h2>
            <a href="/beers/@beer.url">@beer.name</a>
        </div>
    }

    note: thanks to toString() method in the model @@beer is a shorthand for @@beer.name

}
```